# How can I change MVC website UI at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, content-management-system

I want to write some code to create a CMS application in ASP .NET MVC, from where user can create/modify their website on the fly.

I have completed most of the project and it is working fine with the default UI.

I want users to modify their website UI or install new theme, but I am confused about what should I do so that users can install their own themes or change default views.

Comment: is it enough to change Layout Url according to user preferences, Do you want save user template changes or just css changes?

Answer (score 2):

You can save user template preferences on layout name into db programmatically and get it from db when user login.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.UserLayout = GetUserLayout(); // brings user layout preferences
    Return View();
}
```

and on top of your index view

```
 @{
    Layout = ViewBag.UserLayout;
}
```

Comment: This approach is good I I only wants to change the HTML/CSS . But I want user to completely rewrite the Views an upload it to some directory. Then I want to programmatically want to use that directory for views rendering

Comment: I guess you are trying create new layout for per user. for example 10.000 layout.cshtml for 10.000 user? are you sure to do this, you can save user css changes into db and get user css preferences with model.

Comment: Its not per user base setting, its about the admin can change the website layout anytime. I want to create a mvc website where I have a control panel from where I can set the template, and the website then can pick the theme folder for views at run time

Comment: So you can Create a model to hold user layout template preferences and  add this into db so  you will be able to show last state of your website template